# CollectionView in MAUI for Windows raises index was out of range

Tags: maui

I have a `ContentPage` with this `CollectionView`.

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding GameList}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10" ColumnSpacing="15">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding OriginalWord}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding RightWord}" FontAttributes="Italic" />
                </StackLayout>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Translate}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

In the viewmodel, I have a `List` of `GameItem` defined like the following code:

```
public class GameWordList
{
    public string OriginalWord { get; set; }
    public string RightWord { get; set; }
    public string Translate { get; set; }
    public bool IsRight { get; set; }
}

[ObservableProperty] private List<GameWordList> _gameList;
```

I add items in this list in the viewmodel when the user clicks on a button via a `Command`.

```
    public ICommand ConfirmCommand => new Command(ConfirmWord);
    private async void ConfirmWord()
    {
       // ...
       GameList.Add(new GameWordList() { ... });
    }
```

When I show the `CollectionView`, I get this error only for Windows:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')

[image]

[image]

If I remove the `CollectionView` the app is working.

### Update Stacktrace

As requested, here the Stacktrace:

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexMustBeLessException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.ItemTemplateContextList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1.ToAbiHelper.GetAt(UInt32 index)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1.Vftbl.Do_Abi_GetAt_0[TAbi](Void* thisPtr, UInt32 index, TAbi& __return_value__)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverridesMethods.MeasureOverride(IObjectReference _obj, Size availableSize)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.Do_Abi_MeasureOverride_0(IntPtr thisPtr, Size availableSize, Size* result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.GetDesiredSizeFromHandler(IViewHandler viewHandler, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.ComputeDesiredSize(IView view, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.MeasureOverride(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.SecondMeasurePass()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.MeasureCells()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.Measure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.Do_Abi_MeasureOverride_0(IntPtr thisPtr, Size availableSize, Size* result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.GetDesiredSizeFromHandler(IViewHandler viewHandler, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.ComputeDesiredSize(IView view, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.MeasureOverride(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.FirstMeasurePass()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.MeasureCells()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.Measure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AndExpandLayoutManager.Measure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.Do_Abi_MeasureOverride_0(IntPtr thisPtr, Size availableSize, Size* result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.GetDesiredSizeFromHandler(IViewHandler viewHandler, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.ComputeDesiredSize(IView view, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.MeasureOverride(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.SecondMeasurePass()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.MeasureCells()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.Measure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.Do_Abi_MeasureOverride_0(IntPtr thisPtr, Size availableSize, Size* result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.GetDesiredSizeFromHandler(IViewHandler viewHandler, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.LayoutExtensions.ComputeDesiredSize(IView view, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.MeasureOverride(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.SecondMeasurePass()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.GridStructure.MeasureCells()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.GridLayoutManager.Measure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AndExpandLayoutManager.Measure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IFrameworkElementOverrides.Do_Abi_MeasureOverride_0(IntPtr thisPtr, Size availableSize, Size* result)
```

Comment: Do you have a fixed size for `GameList`?

Comment: No, but now I add only 5 items

Comment: Please show the stack trace as text

Comment: @Julian in the post

Comment: I like to remark that this piece of code is working for iOS and Android.

Comment: The reason seems to me like you are not running this code on MainThread, any changes you made to a CollectionView bounded property should be made on MainThread or it will throw an exception

Comment: I think the changes are made on the some thread. This code is working for other platforms. If the changes are made in a different thread, I should have the some issue everywhere.

Comment: @FreakyAli Ideally, ViewModels wouldn't know anything about the MainThread. Bindings work based on the `PropertyChanged` event and are updated on the MainThread by the View itself. The properties that are bound do not need to be updated on the MainThread for this.

Comment: @Julian, ideally that would be true, but there is a problem with collections. Bad things can happen if background thread is altering collection, and main thread is displaying. I’ve seen this on iOS in X-Forms as an occasional collection changed exception.

Comment: @FreakyAli, commands are called from UI code; they run on MainThread. So that shouldn’t be the cause here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is there an `await` inside `ConfirmWord`? If so, will need to see the  complete contents of that method. And as a test, make a version of method that adds an item with hardcoded values. No await; as simple as possible. Still fail? You might need to make a public github repo with just enough code for someone to reproduce the error.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you for your suggestion. I'll do it

Comment: @Julian @ToolmakerSteve I might be wrong but I thought that the `Add` method of a collection doesn't trigger a property changed event correct me if I am wrong though...

Comment: @FreakyAli The `Add()` method doesn't trigger a `PropertyChanged` event on the collection, but it will trigger a [CollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged) event which normally should also update the binding. That's the whole purpose of having an ***Observable**Collection*

Comment: @Julian That's my point he's not using an ObserveableCollection...

Comment: but I added `ObservableProperty` to this `List`

Comment: That does not make it an `ObserveableCollection` bro that's a separate type, your `List<GameWordList> _gameList;` should be `ObserveableCollection<GameWordList> _gameList;` if you want CollectionChanged to trigger

Comment: @FreakyAli ah, yes, that's right. I just undeleted my original answer to this which points that part out.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not solve the index-out-of-range problem, I see two issues here:

1. `GameList` is not initialized in the beginning and it's not apparent from your code when or where this is done
2. Changes to `GameList` will not be reflected in the UI, because `List<T>` does not invoke `PropertyChanged` events when items are added or removed, you should be using `ObservableCollection<T>` instead:

```cs
[ObservableProperty] private ObservableCollection<GameWordList> _gameList = new();
```